# Program always logs in, even if username is not correct

Tags: c#, authentication, dialog

I've got a problem. When my mainForm starts up, the user first sees a dialogForm where they have to login/make a new user. Which in the past worked fine. This was the code:

```
            private void loginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {
            var sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(inlogNaamTextbox.Text + ".\\Login.txt");
            gebruikersnaam = sr.ReadLine();
            passwoord = sr.ReadLine();
            sr.Close();

            if (onthoudMij.Checked)
            {
                Properties.Settings.Default.Gebruikersnaam = inlogNaamTextbox.Text;
                Properties.Settings.Default.Passwoord = inlogPasswoordTextbox.Text;
                Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
            }

            if (gebruikersnaam == inlogNaamTextbox.Text && passwoord == inlogPasswoordTextbox.Text)
            {
                klasseGebruikersnaam.gebruikersnaam = inlogNaamTextbox.Text;
                MessageBox.Show("Je bent nu ingelogd!", "Succes!");
                this.Dispose();
            }

            else
                MessageBox.Show("Gebruikersnaam of wachtwoord fout!", "Fout!");
        }

        catch (System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("De gebruiker bestaat niet!", "Fout!");
        }

    }
```

And I called this form on my mainForm load event. Now the problem was that whenever I tried to go back to the MainForm while in my program, the dialogForm would pop up since it was connected to the mainForm loadevent.

So to solve this problem I added this to the program.cs

```
     using (var loginForm = new startForm())
{
    if (loginForm.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        Application.Run(new indexForm()); 
    }
```

I asigned the loginForm acceptbutton --> loginButton & dialogresult --> Yes

But now here's the problem whenever I try to login the program opens always. So even when at the login I enter a non-existing password (the program shows a messagebox saying it doesn't exist) and then after clicking ok, the program still opens even though it shouldn't.

any way around this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the user fails to authenticate you need to comunicate back that failure.
So add this line to your button click

```
           .....
       }
       else
       {
            MessageBox.Show("Gebruikersnaam of wachtwoord fout!", "Fout!");
            this.DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;
       }
```

Now in the `Program.cs` you don't fall inside the condition

```
if (loginForm.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    Application.Run(new indexForm()); 
}
```

because, in case of error, the result of `loginForm` will be `DialogResult.Cancel`.

However, a better approach would be to stay inside the loginForm unless your user asks to cancel the login and stop the application. In this case I would change to

```
    ....
  else
  {
      MessageBox.Show("Gebruikersnaam of wachtwoord fout!", "Fout!");
      this.DialogResult = DialogResult.None;
  }
```

Applying the `DialogResult.None` enum value to the `DialogResult` property of the form will abort the closing process of a Dialog form and will allow your user to correct the invalid input given.

A last note: This should be applied also inside the exception block

```
    catch (System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("De gebruiker bestaat niet!", "Fout!");
        this.DialogResult = DialogResult.None;
    }
```

Comment: Don't forget the exception block

Comment: Jusy to note something. When I put the ** this.DialogResult = DialogResult.None;** in my catch everything works fine. but when I also include it in my else , my program just closes down whenever a non-existing username is entered? Well not a problem since it works , but do you know how this is possible?

Comment: Never mind just read your comments again , it was all there :D Sorry for my dumbness.

Answer (score 0):

> But now here's the problem whenever I try to login the program opens always. So even when at the login I enter a non-existing password (the program shows a messagebox saying it doesn't exist) **and then after clicking ok, the program still opens even though it shouldn't.**

Yes, because your code says that the program should run if the result of the dialog box is OK:

```
if (loginForm.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    Application.Run(new indexForm()); 
}
```

To fix it, either modify your loginForm code so that the OK button is not clickable unless the credentials are valid, or modify your code shown here so that it tests for a different condition.